# Why is this not a valid xpath in Python (Selenium)?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

In Python (Spyder/Anaconda) I have:

```
ExcelIconXpath = "//*[contains(@id='pagePane0_divBlock0_')]"

ExcelIcon = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=ExcelIconXpath)
```

And I get the following error message:

> Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[contains(@id='pagePane0_divBlock0_')] because of the following error:
> SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document':
> The string **'//*[contains(@id='pagePane0_divBlock0_')]'** *is not a valid XPath expression*.

Comment: Check my response and if it solved your issue, don't forget to mark it as accepted (green checkmark under voting buttons).

Answer (score 1):

It's not a very good error message, is it? Your expression is incorrect because the `contains()` function requires two arguments and you have only supplied one. The value you have supplied is the result of the equality comparison

`@id='pagePane0_divBlock0_'`

which is a boolean; it doesn't make any sense to supply a boolean as the input to `contains()`.

You need to decide whether you actually want to do an equality comparison or a substring (contains) comparison, and then use one or the other rather than mixing them up.

Answer (score 0):

The correct xpath expression would be

```
"//*[contains(@id, 'pagePane0_divBlock0_')]"
```

Here is a good intro into xpath: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

Of course, given you're not waiting on that element to load/be clickable, there might be other issues you might be facing (outside the scope of your original question).

Comment: It might be that the correct expression is actually `//*[@id = 'pagePane0_divBlock0_']` -- we have no way of knowing.